# Excel formula to add rank column in excel sheet based on two columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to add rank column in my excel sheet based on Date and grouped by type

Here is the sample table:

| Type | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 Bedroom | 1/5/2024 |
| 1 Bedroom | 1/1/2024 |
| Studio | 12/31//2023 |
| Studio | 1/4/2024 |
| Studio | 12/30/2023 |

I want to add a rank column based on Date so for example for 1 bedroom the rank for 1/5 will be 2 and for 1/1 will be 1 and then for studio 12/31 the rank is 1. Here is the desired output:

| Type | Date | Index |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 Bedroom | 1/5/2024 | 2 |
| 1 Bedroom | 1/1/2024 | 1 |
| Studio | 1/4/2024 | 2 |
| Studio | 12/30/2023 | 1 |

Thanks for you help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use COUNTIFS()

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,"<="&B2)
```

[image]

---

If one has the dynamic spill functionality then one formula will spill the results:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,A2:A5,B:B,"<="&B2:B5)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Scott-Craner . If I add new a column Status (Values : ACTIVE, INACTIVE). How can I modify the formula to ignore Inactive rows in the count

Comment: That is a new question and as such gets its own post.